# in VB, Why is "Value" not a member of "control" when "Text" is a member of "control"?

Tags: vb.net, class, properties, member

The for loop for the textbox_Analog is working fine.
But the same approach for the GraphProcessBar does not work.
The error given is that Value is not a member of control. As far as I can find in Microsoft online guides, both Text and Value are properties of their objects. Can someone point out why one method works but the other doesn't?
Is there another solution to this problem?
The both the textbox and the progress bar are standard windows forms controls.

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 7 Step 1
Me.Controls("TextBox_Analog" & i).Text = AnalogPins(i) 'Works fine
Next

For i As Int = 0 To 7 Step 1
Me.Controls("GraphProgressBar" & i).Value = PinStatesSTR(i) 'Does not work
Next

'What I'm left doing - calling out each line individually
GraphProgressBar0.Value = PinStatesSTR(0)
GraphProgressBar1.Value = PinStatesSTR(1)
GraphProgressBar2.Value = PinStatesSTR(2)
GraphProgressBar3.Value = PinStatesSTR(3)
GraphProgressBar4.Value = PinStatesSTR(4)
GraphProgressBar5.Value = PinStatesSTR(5)
GraphProgressBar6.Value = PinStatesSTR(6)
GraphProgressBar7.Value = PinStatesSTR(7)
```

Comment: Me.Controls("GraphProgressBar" & i) will be giving you an object of type Control which doesn't have a value property.  You probably want to cast that into the correct type (Whatever GraphProgressBar0 is) to access it's properties.

Answer (score 2):

Because `Value` is not a member of `Control` while `Text` is a member of `Control`. Read [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control?view=netframework-4.8.1#properties) (which you should already have done) and you'll see that for yourself. `Value` is a member of `ProgressBar` so, if you want to access that property, you need a `ProgressBar` reference:

```vb
For i = 0 To 7
    DirectCast(Controls("GraphProgressBar" & i), ProgressBar).Value = PinStatesSTR(i)
Next
```